# why browser report error when a shape call the function draggable()?

Tags: konvajs, konva

i want to make the shape draggable when i select the shape and undraggable when unselected
why browser report draggable is not a function?

When the instance is initialized it is undraggable

```
draw(Map, points) {
        var poly = new Konva.Line({
            // points: [10,10,100,0,100,100,0,100],
            points: points,
            stroke: 'blue',
            strokeWidth: 5,
            closed: true,
            // draggable: true,
            name: 'polygon'
        });
        poly.draggable(false)
        Map.stage.findOne("#draw").add(poly)
        Map.stage.findOne("#tr").nodes([poly])

        if(points.length == 2){
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.onload = function() {
                var yoda = new Konva.Image({
                    x: points[0]-20,
                    y: points[1]-20,
                    image: imageObj,
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    name:'finishBtn'
                });
            
                // add the shape to the layer
                Map.stage.findOne("#draw").add(yoda);
            };
            imageObj.src = '/src/assets/drawmap/ok.png';
        }

        return poly
    }
```

when click the shape i want to make the shape draggable ,the node #tr is a transformer,got the selected shapes by the function nodes(),i tried to not use transformer,directly use the stage.getChildren() to get shapes and call draggable() but failed also

```
Map.stage.on('click tap', function(e) {
            // if we are selecting with rect, do nothing
            if (this.findOne('#selectionRectangle').visible()) {
                return;
            }
            if (Map.curTool !== tool.pick) {
                return;
            }

            // if click on empty area - remove all selections
            // console.warn('单击事件是否在舞台', e.target === this)
            if (e.target === this) {
                this.findOne("#tr").nodes([]);
                return;
            }

            // do nothing if clicked NOT on our rectangles
            if (!e.target.hasName('rect') && !e.target.hasName('polygon') && !e.target.hasName('image')) {
                return;
            }

            // do we pressed shift or ctrl?
            const metaPressed = e.evt.shiftKey || e.evt.ctrlKey || e.evt.metaKey;
            const isSelected = this.findOne("#tr").nodes().indexOf(e.target) >= 0;

            if (!metaPressed && !isSelected) {
                // if no key pressed and the node is not selected
                // select just one
                this.findOne("#tr").nodes([e.target]);
            } else if (metaPressed && isSelected) {
                // if we pressed keys and node was selected
                // we need to remove it from selection:
                const nodes = this.findOne("#tr").nodes().slice(); // use slice to have new copy of array
                // remove node from array
                nodes.splice(nodes.indexOf(e.target), 1);
                this.findOne("#tr").nodes(nodes);
            } else if (metaPressed && !isSelected) {
                // add the node into selection
                const nodes = this.findOne("#tr").nodes().concat([e.target]);
                this.findOne("#tr").nodes(nodes);
            }
            
            let nodes = Map.stage.findOne("#draw").findOne("#tr").nodes()
            for(var i of nodes){
                console.log(i.draggable,i.getClassName(),i.getName())
                i.draggable(true);
            }

        });
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3gac.png)
but the browser report draggable is not a function

Comment: please add the text of the error message to your question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Check your code. Konva uses functions to set attributes, so we use node.draggable(true) and NOT node.draggable=true. This is a common and simple mistake to make - I do it regularly. It is also easy to think there is a bug in the lib but there are many users of Konva and this has not been reported in issues on Github or on the Konva Discord channel. Please check your code again.

Answer (score 0):

From your `console.log` I see that `i.draggable` is `true`. But it should not be a boolean. It should be a function. Most likely, you overwrite the built-in function with the boolean value. I don't see such code in your sample. You may have it somewhere else.

Don't do this:

```js
node.draggable = true;
```

Do this:

```js
node.draggable(true);
```

Comment: i did node.draggable(true); in second code snippet, i guess the "i" is not a node? but the className of "i" is Line, and i make sure i didn't overwrite the function